# How to save files with the lowest possible weight

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pickle

I am trying to save some data to a file using pickle.
My starting list has the form:

```
 a1 = [[190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 9, 60, 62], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 9, 61, 65], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 9, 60, 63], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 9, 61, 65], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 8, 48, 50], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 9, 61, 64], [190, 187, 27, 24, 4, 1, 0, 2, 6, 8, 48, 51]]
```

After leaving only the first and last digits from the sub-lists:

```
a2 = [[190, 62], [190, 65], [190, 63], [190, 65], [190, 50], [190, 64], [190, 51]]
```

And after my base-32 coding:

```
a3 = [['5x', '1x'], ['5x', '21'], ['5x', '1c'], ['5x', '21'], ['5x', '1o'], ['5x', '20'], ['5x', '1p']]
```

File with list 'a1' has 224 bytes, with list 'a2' has 84 bytes, and with list 'a3' has 182 bytes. Why is the file with the 'a3' list bigger than the file with the 'a2' list? Do quotes enlarge the file? 
It seemed to me that, for example, "5x" would take less than "190", and at the same time would reduce the weight of the entire file. Are there other more effective ways of storing such data in files?

Comment: The quotes indicate a string literal. You are storing strings of characters. `190` is an integer, and probably uses 32 bits. "190" is a string of characters which probably also use 32 bits, 8 bits per character and a null terminator. These are rough estimates, someone else should be able to answer with better references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the quotes that increase the size, it's the fact that it's a string so it has to be denoted as such - when pickled, via optcodes.

Pickle is also not really intended to be very space-efficient (or even fast) unless you use at least `protocol=2` while pickling.

If you're after a minimum size (without compression) while storing strings, CSV should do it:

```
import csv

a3 = [['5x', '1x'], ['5x', '21'], ['5x', '1c'], ['5x', '21'], ['5x', '1o'],
      ['5x', '20'], ['5x', '1p']]

with open("saved_data.csv", "wt", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(a3)
```

This will produce a 49 bytes CSV file (`saved_data.csv`) and you can't get lower than that without compression. By comparison, even pickling with `protocol=4` will take 93 bytes for this data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Meh... easy to encode that data in **14** bytes. (Not even using the fact that every sublist has the same first value.)

Comment: interesting. how?

Comment: it's even better because in the original data in the first position I have different values :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski `b''.join(map(bytes, a2))`

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski Does that work for you? If it doesn't (i.e., if your numbers aren't actually all in byte range), the larger point still stands: The more you can tell us about your data, the smaller we can make it.